# Solidity Syntax error with changing mint rate uint

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am new to solidity, and am wondering why this isn't working.

```
//Mint Price
uint256 public mintRate = 0.025 ether;

function changeMintRate(uint256 _mintRate) public onlyOwner{
        uint256 public mintRate = _mintRate ether;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
uint256 public mintRate = _mintRate ether;
```

Please do:

```
mintRate = _mintRate ether;
```

Comment: Thank you, I was redefining the variable.